# Why Doesn't This Do an Implicit Cast to the Converting Constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion, typecast-operator, explicit-conversion

So I have this code:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() { cout << "default\n"; }
    Foo(const long long) { cout << "implicit\n"; }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(const short param) : param(param) {}
    operator long long() const { return static_cast<long long>(param); }
    const short param;
};
```

I would have thought that `Foo foo = Bar(13)` would have used my implicit cast and then the converting constructor. [But it errors](https://ideone.com/MUQQfR):

> error: conversion from `Bar` to non-scalar type `Foo` requested

This works fine though: `Foo foo(Bar(13))`. Why is my implicit cast used for explicit converting construction, but not for implicit converting construction?

The rules I got from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization say:

> The result of the conversion, which is a prvalue expression if a converting constructor was used, is then used to direct-initialize the object

Comment: There is no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is an explicit conversion.

Comment: Can both a converting constructor and a casting operator be considered implicit conversions though? I wanted to differentiate.

Comment: Doesn't matter because either way there is no such thing as an "implicit cast" yet you have used the term three times.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit implicit conversion would be considered correct?

Comment: If that's what you meant to say. I don't know, because you used a term that doesn't exist!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wanted to know why the `Bar::operator long long()` cast can't be used to implicitly use the `Foo::Foo(const long long)` converting constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly the implicit conversion from `Bar` to `long long`, and the one from `long long` to `Foo` are both user-defined conversion.

`Foo foo = Bar(13);` perform [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), the compiler will try to convert `Bar` to `Foo` implicitly. Two implicit conversions are required, i.e. converting `Bar` to `long long` and then converting `long long` to `Foo`. But only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) sequence.

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>
> 2) zero or one user-defined conversion;
>
> 3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.
>
> A user-defined conversion consists of zero or one non-explicit single-argument constructor or non-explicit conversion function call

`Foo foo(Bar(13));` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). The constructors of `Foo` would be examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. Only one implicit user-defined conversion (from `Bar` to `long long`) is required; after that `Foo::Foo(long long)` is called to construct `foo` directly.

Comment: So more conversions are allowed in explicit conversion? Cause that has to do 2 conversions (if we're considering the converting constructor a conversion.)

Comment: @JonathanMee *So more conversions are allowed in explicit conversion* Sure,  you can specify as many casts as you want if you do it explicitly.

Comment: There is only one implicit conversion in `Foo foo(Bar(13))`, from `Bar` to `long long`.  But `Foo foo = Bar(13)` requires the `Bar` be converted to `long long` and then to `Foo` so that `foo` can be copy-constructed.

Comment: @JonathanMee Answer revised.

Answer (score 2):

As you use copy initialization then according to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization **must produce T directly from the initializer**, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

emphasis is mine. This is not the case.